# PHP missing tmp_name in $_FILES

Tags: php, file-upload

till last week it was possible to upload files to our server.
But now it isn't possible and i get the errorcode "6" (UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR).

```
array(2) {
 ["doc_file1"]=>
   array(5) {
     ["name"]=>
     string(21) "123.pdf"
     ["type"]=>
     string(0) ""
     ["tmp_name"]=>
     string(0) ""
     ["error"]=>
     int(6)
     ["size"]=>
     int(0)
}
["doc_file2"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["type"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["error"]=>
    int(4)
    ["size"]=>
    int(0)
 }
}
```

We haven't changed anything, so nothing that i know.

I read that if no "Upload Dir" is set in the php.ini, php take the system tmp directory?!

I tried sys_get_temp_dir() and get back "/tmp".

so i don't know why i get this error now?! Any ideas to solve it?

The size of the file i want to upload is 91kb.

Comment: Are you sure the user that runs PHP (or apache?) has write access to `/tmp`?

Comment: check permissions on the tmp folder and make sure your existing one isn't filled up

Comment: looks like someone changed the tmp directory varriable in `php.ini` or permission problem..   find `upload_tmp_dir
` in `php.ini`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to all for your help, the problem was the permissions/owner on the tmp directory.
We don't who had changed it but we changed it and now it works great.